# Why is the Comments Composer collapsed?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I have the setting in Comment Moderation Tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) to always show the comment composer. But it's not working when there are several comments. It just displays a link that says 'Add a comment'.